# Hitting Max APache Connections - Am I Being Hacked?

Tags: php, apache

There is some very strange activity happening on my server today. I am hitting Max Apache connections but cannot find anything that could be causing it (I don't think I am being DOS attacked or anything).

I checked my Apache logs and found some weird things.

First:

```
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] --2013-08-13 09:41:13--  http://heatinasnap.net/gs.txt, referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] Resolving heatinasnap.net... 173.254.28.65, referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] Connecting to heatinasnap.net|173.254.28.65|:80... connected., referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found, referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] 2013-08-13 09:41:13 ERROR 404: Not Found., referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:13 2013] [error] [client 85.76.3.157] , referer: http://example.net/forum/index.php

[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] --2013-08-13 09:41:31--  http://heatinasnap.net/gs.txt, referer: http://example.net/members
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] Resolving heatinasnap.net... 173.254.28.65, referer: http://example.net/members
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] Connecting to heatinasnap.net|173.254.28.65|:80... connected., referer: http://example.net/members
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found, referer: http://example.net/members
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] 2013-08-13 09:41:31 ERROR 404: Not Found., referer: http://example.net/members
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:31 2013] [error] [client 112.198.64.88] , referer: http://example.net/members

[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] --2013-08-13 09:41:33--  http://heatinasnap.net/gs.txt, referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6747
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] Resolving heatinasnap.net... 173.254.28.65, referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6747
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] Connecting to heatinasnap.net|173.254.28.65|:80... connected., referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6747
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found, referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6747
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] 2013-08-13 09:41:33 ERROR 404: Not Found., referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6747
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:33 2013] [error] [client 141.138.54.172] , referer: http://example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=674
```

I have no idea what heatinasnap.net is (never heard of it).

And second, some sort of vulnerability scanner:

```
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:40 2013] [error] [client 220.248.145.30] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Match of "rx ^apache.*perl" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent" required. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "55"] [id "990011"] [msg "Request Indicates an automated program explored the site"] [severity "NOTICE"] [hostname "www.mysite.net"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "UgpFpK339QIAAFT1Y2MAAAAC"]
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:41 2013] [error] [client 220.248.145.30] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Match of "rx ^apache.*perl" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent" required. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "55"] [id "990011"] [msg "Request Indicates an automated program explored the site"] [severity "NOTICE"] [hostname "mysite.net"] [uri "/406.shtml"] [unique_id "UgpFpa339QIAAGfpU5MAAAUD"]
[Tue Aug 13 09:41:41 2013] [error] [client 220.248.145.30] File does not exist: /home/hellohel/public_html/406.shtm
```

Here is my current apache status:

```
CPU Usage: u147.51 s128.44 cu2247.28 cs0 - 146% CPU load
147 requests/sec - 2.3 MB/second - 16.4 kB/request
512 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers
```

I did not see any MaxClient errors in Apache though. There is definitely something weird going on...can anyone provide some insight?

**Update:**

The cause of the apache hitting max-clients turned out to be a slowloris DOS attack, which was fixed with the apache `Mod_Antiloris`. Install instructions here:

http://www.hostingdiscussion.com/hardware-server-configuration/27399-installing-mod_antiloris-mitigate-slowloris-dos-attack.html

**Update2:**

```
I am not sure if it was luck or not, but the slowloris thing just solved it for a few minutes. It went back to 512 (max) connections shortly after. I am seeing some very high CPU load on simple scripts so I am wondering if it has something to do with handling large log files. One is just a css file taking up `24.66 CPU`. Check out just a few processes:

Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-0 31154   0/45/45 R   23.85   3   1   0.0 0.47    0.47    ?   ?   ..reading..
0-0 31154   0/36/36 _   24.66   0   1   0.0 0.43    0.43    81.152.251.175  mysite.net  GET /css/dwn.css HTTP/1.1
0-0 31154   0/33/33 R   23.92   2   179 0.0 0.69    0.69    ?   ?   ..reading..
0-0 31154   0/1/1   W   0.07    119 0   0.0 0.00    0.00    117.102.163.190 mysite.net  POST /includes/offers/ajax.php HTTP/1.1
0-0 31154   1/64/64 C   24.74   0   1   26.8    1.85    1.85    24.127.122.188  mysite.net  GET /images/soc.png HTTP/1.1
0-0 31154   0/51/51 _   24.87   0   899 0.0 0.78    0.78    86.111.144.194  mysite.net  GET /includes/offers/window.php?file=57860&tooltip=true HTTP/1.
0-0 31154   0/18/18 R   11.00   77  1   0.0 0.27    0.27    ?   ?   ..reading..
```

Comment: it will be better if you ask this question at [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com). They will be able to help you better

Comment: Erm, have you configured that thing as a proxy? Why would _your_ webserver request stuff from that unfamiliar domain?

Comment: I have not set it up as any sort of proxy. I am wondering the same thing...is my site compromised? I am looking in the source files but cannot find references to that domain.

Comment: Well, at least I can't get the website in your profile to behave like proxy... No code like curl thingamayigs which might do something like this?

Comment: @Wrikken - they could be there if my site is compromised, but I have not found them. Is there anyway to use the Apache log to figure out which scripts the error comes from? Also, do you have any recommendations for hiring someone to look into these sort of things? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @hellohellosharp: not easily... on a quiet server you might be able to link normal access-log entries to the behavior. But if it's compromized... best get a professional from _somewhere_. VPSes are cheaper then managed VPSes for a reason, and if your project becomes serious, I'd pay the money for managed if you're not comfortable in a sysadmin role. However, quick fix for quiet servers is usually: backup database, request a clean install of your OS, and reupload your code & database. Best be safe.

Comment: Have you looked at the code on the pages where the errors are coming from? `http://mysite.net/forum/index.php`

Comment: I used `grep` to search for instances of "heatinasnap" in that directory but it found nothing.

Comment: @Wrikken - It is actually on a dedicated server. I will see what I can do about hiring someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your site is opening remote files because those messages indicate that your Apache server is performing a look-up through DNS.

**To look for bad code**

You would need to figure out what method they're using to access the box. Then look into that code and try to find something out of the ordinary. They will typically use things like `exec()` and `base64_decode()` to hide the code, then you can `grep` for those. Also `grep` for things like `fopen()`, `fread()`, `file_get_contents()`, and even `curl_init()`. If you find any of these scripts in places where you're not expecting them, then that will be your exploit.

You should be able to look for outbound traffic on the box using something like [`conntrackd`](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/support.html), `ntop`, `argus`, `bro-ids`, and `sancp`.

**Attempt at a quick fix**

Go into the `php.ini` file and [check the system configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) for `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include`. It looks as though someone is trying to get your site to open the txt file from their site (where the payload exists).

If those settings allow remote opening, then that's how they're causing this behavior. Someone more than likely opened a file on your server from their server and caused an exploit.

If they have code on your box, then you will need to wipe out the contents of the box and update the code from one of your back-ups once the `php.ini` file has been fixed. Otherwise they could try to change settings on the front-end with their already hosted code using things like `ini_set`.

Making no changes to the code or settings and restoring from backup will not prevent the behavior. Additionally, you can use something like `IPtables` to block all outbound requests to `heatinasnap.net` and its resolved IP [173.254.28.65].

If you're using something like `file_get_contents` it will be disabled by making this change. cURL on the other hand [uses its own libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php) and is not going to be affected by the change. Any code on the server can still use cURL though, (even if it's not yours).

**Update for DOS Attack**

Since you think this is a DOS instead, you might try using [mod_reqtimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html). Good settings would be:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=10 body=30
```

Comment: Thanks! `allow_url_fopen` was set to On, but I could not find any allow_url_include setting. Will turning off allow_url_fopen disable functions like curl and file_get_contents (these are used on my site)? Also, i am not in a position to re upload everything right now, but is there a way I can scan for root kits and malicious code?

Comment: You can run something like Rootkit Hunter. It's called `rkhunter` in some of the repositories. http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html